# Selected Items using MVVM in WinRT

Tags: mvvm, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm struggling to find a way to bind the SelectedItems property in a ListView to the view model.

Previously I used this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412417/Managing-Multiple-selection-in-View-Model-NET-Metr which no longer works in the RTM release.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out binding to the attached property was failing because the type of the attached property was being seen as

*From the output window in Visual Studio:*

> type ('null')

After further research it became apparent that any generic class would fail to bind with this exact error. As a quick fix I simply changed the type to "object".

Comment: Did you change the type of your SelectedItems object to object?

Comment: I changed `ObservableCollection<TypedObject>` to `ObservableCollection<object>` - You can then cast this instance using `collection.Cast<TypedObject>()`.

Answer (score 5):

You could look at the ListViewExtensions.BindableSelection from the [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://jupitertoolkit.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.

Comment: This gave me the same error as before - binding to a type ('null').

Answer (score -1):

You can direct bind the selected item to another ui element or a property in your mvvm class