# Binding/Maintaining GridView selected items in MVVM

Tags: c#, gridview, mvvm, windows-8

I have a GridView configured as such:

```
SelectionMode="Multiple"
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMyObj, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

So then in my ViewModel, I have the following property for the SelectedItem:

```
private MyObj selectedMyObj;
public MyObj SelectedMyObj
{
    get { return selectedMyObj; }
    set
    {
        selectedMyObj = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

This works in an odd way (imho). When I click an Item in my GridView, it is bound to `SelectedMyObj`. If I click on *any other* item in the GridView, `SelectedMyObj` is never updated with the current selection. If I *unselect* the first item I selected, `SelectedMyObj` is then updated with the item that has been selected the next longest.

Perhaps this is a bit of a digression, but the real problem I'm wishing to solve is *how do I persist my selected items*? When one item is selected, I want to add/remove it from the master list of selected Items and persist that to local storage. This doesn't appear to be very straight forward when using MVVM in Windows 8 short of using a 3rd party MVVM framework.

thanks!

Comment: I haven't really played with WinRT gridview, so not answer, just some references : [Selected Items using MVVM in WinRT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12500804/2998271) and [article from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412417/Managing-Multiple-selection-in-View-Model-NET-Metr)

Comment: it sounds to me like the best option is just to upgrade to VS 2013 and upgrade the project to 8.1. Otherwise, it sounds like a lot of 8.0 specific hacks.